# "TypeError: (0 , ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function" when writing tests in hardhat with typescript

Tags: javascript, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, typescript, test

i get this error when i run this test:

```
typescript
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { Ballot } from "../typechain-types";

const PROPOSALS = ["Proposal1", "Proposal2", "Proposal3"];

describe("Ballot", function () {
  let ballotContract: Ballot;

  beforeEach("Deploys the contract.", async () => {
    const ballotFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Ballot");
    const prop1 = ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(PROPOSALS[0]);
    const prop2 = ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(PROPOSALS[1]);
    const prop3 = ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(PROPOSALS[2]);
    ballotContract = await ballotFactory.deploy(PROPOSALS);
    await ballotContract.waitForDeployment();
  });
```

i'm using ethers v5 too so i'm confused as to why i get this error. i've upgraded it just to be sure it's not from there but it doesn't work. here's the version of my hardhat: ^2.16.1. it's supposed to return PROPOSALS but it throws that error.